# Got global.process.platform undefined error after upgrade to nativescript 6

Tags: nativescript

I use vs code for debugging my Nativescript App, it works well in Nativescript 5.4.2, until I tried Nativescript 6.0.3 I get this error when build for ios

> 'file not found:
>   /Users/microshop/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FoxCloudApp-dzpjhqlpezduwgdbrmlthkddzaqs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FoxCloudApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FoxCloudApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o'

- I tried to downgrade to 5.4.2, still not work.
- The xcode works, but I need vs code to debug.
- tns build ios --for-device also works.

> Webpack compilation complete. Project successfully prepared (ios)
>   Building project... Xcode build...
>   /Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/Pods/ISMessages/ISMessages/Classes/ISMessages.m:198:1:
>   warning: 
>         conflicting return type in implementation of 'accessibilityPerformEscape':
>         'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'bool' [-Wmismatched-return-types]
>   - (bool)accessibilityPerformEscape { ^  ~~~~ In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Target
>   Support Files/ISMessages/ISMessages-prefix.pch:2:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:276:1:
>   note: 
>         previous definition is here
>   - (BOOL)accessibilityPerformEscape NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0); ^  ~~~~ 1 warning generated. Metadata Generator Arguments: 
>   "./objc-metadata-generator", "-verbose", "-output-bin",
>   "/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-i386.bin",
>   "-output-umbrella",
>   "/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/umbrella-i386.h",
>   "-docset-path",
>   "/Users/microshop/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset",
>   "Xclang", "-isysroot",
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk",
>   "-arch", "i386", "-mios-simulator-version-min=9.0", "-std=gnu99",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages/ISMessages.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController/QBImagePickerController.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast/Toast.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/Swift-Modules",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../App_Resources/iOS/src",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-app-sync/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios",
>   "-DCOCOAPODS=1", "-DDEBUG=1",  Clang Arguments:  "-v", "-x",
>   "objective-c", "-fno-objc-arc", "-fmodule-maps", "-ferror-limit=0",
>   "-Wno-unknown-pragmas", "-Wno-ignored-attributes",
>   "-Wno-nullability-completeness", "-Wno-expansion-to-defined",
>   "-D__NATIVESCRIPT_METADATA_GENERATOR=1", "-isysroot",
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk",
>   "-arch", "i386", "-mios-simulator-version-min=9.0", "-std=gnu99",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages/ISMessages.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController/QBImagePickerController.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast/Toast.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/Swift-Modules",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../App_Resources/iOS/src",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-app-sync/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios",
>   "-DCOCOAPODS=1", "-DDEBUG=1",  Merged 663 categories. Result: 40266
>   declarations from 141 top level modules Done! Running time: 5.12762
>   sec  Saving metadata generation's stderr stream to:
>   /Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-generation-stderr-i386.txt
>   Generating metadata for x86_64 Metadata Generator Arguments: 
>   "./objc-metadata-generator", "-verbose", "-output-bin",
>   "/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-x86_64.bin",
>   "-output-umbrella",
>   "/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/umbrella-x86_64.h",
>   "-docset-path",
>   "/Users/microshop/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset",
>   "Xclang", "-isysroot",
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk",
>   "-arch", "x86_64", "-mios-simulator-version-min=9.0", "-std=gnu99",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages/ISMessages.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController/QBImagePickerController.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast/Toast.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/Swift-Modules",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../App_Resources/iOS/src",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-app-sync/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios",
>   "-DCOCOAPODS=1", "-DDEBUG=1",  Clang Arguments:  "-v", "-x",
>   "objective-c", "-fno-objc-arc", "-fmodule-maps", "-ferror-limit=0",
>   "-Wno-unknown-pragmas", "-Wno-ignored-attributes",
>   "-Wno-nullability-completeness", "-Wno-expansion-to-defined",
>   "-D__NATIVESCRIPT_METADATA_GENERATOR=1", "-isysroot",
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk",
>   "-arch", "x86_64", "-mios-simulator-version-min=9.0", "-std=gnu99",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages/ISMessages.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController/QBImagePickerController.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast/Toast.framework/Headers",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/Swift-Modules",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../App_Resources/iOS/src",
>   "-I/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/internal/",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISMessages",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QBImagePickerController",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SSZipArchive",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-app-sync/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-calendar/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/ios",
>   "-F/Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios",
>   "-DCOCOAPODS=1", "-DDEBUG=1",  Merged 663 categories. Result: 40261
>   declarations from 141 top level modules Done! Running time: 5.06372
>   sec  Saving metadata generation's stderr stream to:
>   /Users/microshop/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-generation-stderr-x86_64.txt
>   ~/FoxCloudApp/platforms/ios ld: file not found:
>   /Users/microshop/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FoxCloudApp-dzpjhqlpezduwgdbrmlthkddzaqs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FoxCloudApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FoxCloudApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote:
>   Constructing build description
>   BUILD FAILED
>
> Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65 .

Updated at 26 Aug:

I tried to recreate an empty project, add each plugins, now it build successfully, but get error when start:

> JavaScript error:
>   file:///node_modules/properties/lib/stringify.js:9:17 JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.process.platform')
>   (CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.process.platform')
>   at
>   1   ../node_modules/properties/lib/stringify.js@file:///node_modules/properties/lib/stringify.js:9:17
>   2   **webpack_require**@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
>   3   fn@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
>   4   ../node_modules/properties/lib/write.js@file:///node_modules/properties/lib/write.js:4:23
>   5   **webpack_require**@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
>   6   fn@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
>   7   ../node_modules/properties/lib/index.js@file:///node_modules/properties/lib/index.js:7:19
>   8   **webpack_require**@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
>   9   fn@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
>   10  @file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable/bindable.js:2:27
>   11  ../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable/bindable.js@file:///app/vendor.js:112359:34
>   12  **webpack_require**@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
>   13  fn@file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
>   14  @file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder/component-builder.js:2:25
>   15  ../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder/component-build<…>
>   NativeScript caught signal 6.
>   Native Stack:
>   1   0x10ede184f sig_handler(int)
>   2   0x11352ab1d _sigtramp
>   3   0xffff
>   4   0x1132a501d abort
>   5   0x1130399d1 __cxa_bad_cast
>   6   0x113039b6f default_unexpected_handler()
>   7   0x111a5ce2d _objc_terminate()
>   8   0x113045a2e std::__terminate(void (*)())
>   9   0x1130454eb __cxa_get_exception_ptr
>   10  0x1130454b2 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
>   11  0x111a5cbfa _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
>   12  0x10ed9cd58 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
>   13  0x10ede2d1f -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
>   14  0x10e7aec63 main
>   15  0x1131be541 start
>   16  0x1
>   JS Stack:
>
> Cannot connect to device socket. The error message is 'The application has been terminated.'.

Packages:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "foxcloud.app",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.2"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.2"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@wishtack/reactive-component-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.15",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-app-sync": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.2",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^4.0.0",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.2.2",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.11",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.0.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.7",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^7.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "42f2a6a9c94eaf9c68d2a41e0daaa1a2544bc28f",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```